# Using phantom.cookies with Casperjs

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs, casperjs

In Phantom using

```
phantom.cookies
```

you can access the cookies set in phantom. How can you achieve the same in casperjs?

I tried using

```
this.evaluate(function(){
     return document.cookie;
})
```

However, you don't get the expiry date and also you don't get the json output as with phantom.cookies.

Answer (score 3):

The `phantom` object still exists in CasperJS, so you can use `phantom.cookies` the same way you use it in PhantomJS.

This works even with the SlimerJS engine, because it also implements the `phantom` object.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can use the following in casperjs:

```
this.page.cookies
```

Comment: There is a difference between `phantom.cookies` and `page.cookies` which is that the latter only shows the filtered results for the current protocol+domain.